# Ef Core Select inherited Model

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have the following classes:

```cs
public class User{
    public Guid Id{get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}

public class TestUser : User{
    public string Title {get; set;}
}

public class CustomUser: User{
    public string Value {get; set;}
}
```

The configuration of the classes looks as follows:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<TestUser>().HasBaseType<User>();
modelBuilder.Entity<CustomUser>().HasBaseType<User>();
```

Each class is a seperate Database-Table (TPT).

each class has an DTO class that maps the data to share (UserGetDto, TestUserGetDto, CustomUserGetDto). The Dto-Classes are also inherited.

```cs
public class UserGetDto{}

public class TestUserGetDto : UserGetDto{}

public class CustomUserGetDto : UserGetDto{}
```

Now I want to select the DTOs using LINQ and return the respective DTO. But the switch-Case expression doesn't work:

```cs
public List<UserGetDto> GetUsers(){
    return _context.Users
        .Select(user => user switch{
            User usr when usr is TestUser => new TestUserGetDto(){
                ...
            },
            User usr when usr is CustomUser => new CustomUserGetDto(){ ... },
            _ => new UserGetDto(){...}
        }
        .ToList();
}
```

Is there any other way to select the respective DTOs?

## Update

Experimenting with AutoMapper and referencing to the helpful comments, I found a working solution:

I added a UserProfile with the following Configuration:

```cs
CreateMap<User, UserGet>()
    .ConvertUsing(user => 
        user is TestUser ? new TestUserGet(){...}
        : user is CustomUser ? new CustomUserGet(){...}
        : new UserGet()
    );
```

My first tests seem to work as expected.

> Disadvantage is, that I need to set e.g. TestUserDto manually.

Comment: Show us your Model Configuration code - and [what inheritance strategy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance) are you using (TPH, TPT,  TPCT, TPC, etc)?

Comment: Why cant you use automapper? These logics will be done automatically.

Comment: _"The Dto-Classes are also inherited."_ - Doing that is going to cause problems later on.

Comment: @JyothishBhaskaran You mean not to map the classes into Dtos?

Comment: @JyothishBhaskaran I had a look into AutoMapper and it looks really good and helpful. But unfortunatly it isn't able to recognize derived classes. e.g. if I have List<UserGet> it only puts UserGet instances into it. Not the respective casted class e.g. CustomUserGetDto.

Answer (score 1):

Use Conditional operator instead:

```cs
public List<UserGetDto> GetUsers()
{
    return _context.Users
        .Select(user => 
            user is TestUser ? new TestUserGetDto()
            {
                Title = ((TestUser)user).Title
                ...
            }
            : user is CustomUser ? new CustomUserGetDto()
            {
                Value = ((CustomUser)user).Value
                 ... 
            },
            : new UserGetDto(){...}
        })
        .ToList();
}
```

Comment: I would also add the reason why this happens: IIRC, the switch operator is not supported by the EF's ExpressionTree builder.

Comment: @SergeyKudriavtsev, actually `switch` in Expression Tree  even  should not compile.

Comment: Yeah, exactly. The OP didn't specify what they mean by "switch-Case expression doesn't work" - most likely it meant "does not compile".

Comment: mmh ok. This approach seems to work, but here I need to add (the same) base-class properties foreach variant. Is here any clever trick to avoid it e.g. first to set base-class globally and then select the derviced class using the switch?

Comment: No, it is only one variant. Otherwise we have to build Expression Tree dynamically.